# How to set Image Button to some image in my internal storage (Android)?

Tags: android, image, firebase, button, uri

Help me to set the uri of the image button to the image that i select form the internal storage. I have already given required permissions in the android_manifest.xml file. The problem is that when i browse to the internal storage of phone the images are unselectable.

```
public void onUploadImageClick(View view){
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    galleryIntent.setType("Image/*");
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        uri=data.getData();
        imageButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.image_button);
        imageButton.setImageURI(uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: post your manifest file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void onUploadImageClick(View view){

Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);

}
```

Then in your on activity result method keep this

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent    data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if(requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
    uri=data.getData();
    imageButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.image_button);
    imageButton.setImageURI(uri);
}
```

}

**EDIT**

yes the problem is I forgot to add .Media 
so use this line of code:

```
 Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
```

Comment: already added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> in the manifest.

Comment: @user11 did this fix the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this. You could replace `ImageView` to `ImageButton`

```
 String qrPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Image.png";
 BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
 options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
 Bitmap mustOpen = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(qrPath, options);

 setContentView(R.layout.qr_image);
 ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.qr_image);
 imageView.setImageBitmap(mustOpen);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        uri=data.getData();
        String pathName = uri.toString();
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName);
        imageButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.image_button);
        imageButton.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
}
```